# Is it acceptable to use exceptions instead of verbose null-checks?

Tags: c#, java, exception, null

I recenly encountered this problem in a project: There's a chain of nested objects, e.g.: class A contains an instance variable of class B, which in turns has an instance variable of class C, ..., until we have a node in the tree of class Z.

```
     -----      -----      -----      -----               ----- 
     | A | ---> | B | ---> | C | ---> | D | ---> ... ---> | Z |
     -----      -----      -----      -----               -----
```

Each class provides getters and setters for its members. The parent A instance is created by an XML parser, and it is legal for any object in the chain to be null.

Now imagine that at a certain point in the application, we have a reference to an A instance, and only if it contains a Z object, we must invoke a method on it. Using regular checks, we get this code:

```
    A parentObject;

    if(parentObject.getB() != null &&
        parentObject.getB().getC() != null &&
        parentObject.getB().getC().getD() != null &&
        parentObject.getB().getC().getD().getE() != null &&
        ...
        parentObject.getB().getC().getD().getE().get...getZ() != null){
            parentObject.getB().getC().getD().getE().get...getZ().doSomething();
    }
```

I know that exceptions should not be used for ordinary control flow, but instead of the previous code, I have seen some programmers doing this:

```
    try {
        parentObject.getB().getC().getD().getE().get...getZ().doSomething();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){}
```

The problem with this code is that it may be confuse when maintaining it, since it doesn't show clearly which objects are allowed to be null. But on the other hand is much more concise and less "telescopic".

Is it an acceptable to do this to save development time?
How could the API be redesigned to avoid this problem?

The only thing I can think of to avoid the long null checking is to provide void instances of the nested objects and providing `isValid` methods for each one of them, but wouldn't this create a lot of innecesary objects in memory?

(I've used Java code, but the same question can apply to C# properties)

Thanks.

Comment: You could always have a static NULL object of type A that returns itself.

Comment: @Ivan - You'd need NULL objects of all the types along the way to use that tactic here.

Comment: Is it possible to make some or all of the instance variables read-only (immutable)? You could then ensure (e.g. in the constructor) that the variable is non-null and thereby eliminate the checks.

Comment: I highly recommend watching this video: [The Clean Code Talks - Don't look for things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0). Afterwards you will realize that the null checking and the exception tactic are really just two alternative band-aid solutions to a more fundamental problem. The real answer is: refactor. (If you have access to the code, of course.)

Comment: @Corbett Thanks for the vid. I can't believe I watched it in my free time. I think nulls must be checked sooner or later (I prefer sooner, and yes, screw the testers). But sometimes, as in my example, nulls are legal and there isn't a real need for raising NPEs on instantiation. My question was more about the morality of using exceptions for something they're not really intended for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like to avoid this problem altogether by using an [option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). By adjusting the value returned from these methods/properties to be `Option<T>` rather than `T` the caller can choose how they wish to handle the case of no value.

An option type can either have a contained value or not (but the option itself can never be null), but the caller cannot simply pass it on without unwrapping the value so it forces the caller to deal with the fact there may be no value.

E.g. in C#:

```
class A {
    Option<B> B { get { return this.optB; } }
}

class B {
    Option<C> C { get { return this.optC; } }
}

// and so on
```

If the caller wants to throw, they merely retrieve the value without explicitly checking to see if there is one:

```
A a = GetOne();
D d = a.Value.B.Value.C.Value.D.Value; // Value() will throw if there is no value
```

If the caller wants to just default if any step doesn't have a value, they can perform mapping/binding/projection:

```
A a = GetOne();
D d = a.Convert(a => a.B) // gives the value or empty Option<B>
       .Convert(b => b.C) // gives value or empty Option<C>
       .Convert(c => c.D) // gives value or empty Option<D>
       .ValueOrDefault(new D("No value")); // get a default if anything was empty
```

If the caller wants to default at each stage, they can:

```
A a = GetOne();
D d = a.ValueOrDefault(defaultA)
     .B.ValueOrDefault(defaultB)
     .C.ValueOrDefault(defaultC)
     .D.ValueOrDefault(defaultD);
```

`Option` is not currently part of C# but I imagine one day will be. You can get an implementation by referencing the F# libraries or you may be able to find an implementation on the web. If you'd like mine, let me know and I'll send it to you.

Comment: Just a question: what exactly does the `Convert` in the second snippet? I can understand the lambdas, but I don't see what's the difference with the third snippet.

Comment: @Mister Smith: `Convert` will take an `Option<A>` (for example) and let you run a conversion on the contained value (if there is one) to produce `Option<B>`. What's great is that the conversion works regardless of whether the option is empty or not: a full `Option<A>` gets converted to a full `Option<B>` whereas an empty `Option<A>` gets converted to an empty `Option<B>` with no exceptions or errors. So one can choose both when and how to deal with 'emptiness'.

Comment: @Mister Smith: as an example, if you had an `Option<int>` you can run `optInt.Convert(i => i.ToString())` to produce an `Option<string>` which will succeed even if `optInt` is empty.

Comment: Ok, I only needed empty values to avoid null-checks (my default value would be an empty value), hence my confusion. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use this, you must change the type of your properties from T to Option<T>.  That is a drastic change, for which i would require a drastic reason.  All reference types are nullable by default, so i don't see the added benefit.  What exactly is the purpose of using the Option<T> type?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: so imagine you call a method called `GetIt` that returns a value of type `Banana`. Then you pass that to a method called `DoSomething` that takes a type `Banana` (`DoSomething(Banana)`). If `GetIt` returned a null then you would have passed that null onto `DoSomething` which may in turn pass it on to a number of methods before you eventually end up with a `NullReferenceException` or `ArgumentNullException` at some point divorced from where the null was generated.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: now imagine that you have a method called `GetIt` that returns `Option<Banana>`. Instead of a `null` you'll get an empty option instead. There's no way you can pass an `Option<T>` to the method `DoSomething` because that takes a naked banana (`DoSomething(Banana)`) so you are forced to deal with option: you must either write code to handle the fact it may be empty or you can simply retrieve the value *generating an exception at a site very near to the source of the null*. This is all explained in the link in my answer and illustrated in the examples I gave.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: you don't have to change *all* of your properties from `T` to `Option<T>`: one would only use option where there is a legitimate reason for there to be no value, e.g. in a hashtable like class a `Get` method would return an option because the key looked up may not exists. I wouldn't for a minute suggest blindly changing *every* property.

Comment: @PaulRuane: i understand, using `Option<T>` forces you to deal with possible null values before passing them on to methods that accept T.  To achieve this, you need to mark properties that may return `null` with `Option<T>`.   Even methods that in a current version always return an instance, may later be changed to return null.  To prevent breaking code, you may need to mark that property ahead of time.  You can achieve the same result by letting method `DoSomething(Banana)` check it's inputs (fail fast). That way there is no need for changing your class signatures.

Answer (score 16):

It is bad design if parentObject needs to know that A contains a B which contains a C wich contains.... That way, everything is coupled to everything. You should have a look at the law of demeter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter

parentObject should only call methods on its instance variable B. So, B should provide a method that allows for the decision, e.g.

```
public class A {
  private B myB;
  //...
  public boolean isItValidToDoSomething(){
    if(myB!=null){
      return myB.isItValidToDoSomething();
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Eventually, at the level of Z, the method has to return true.

Imho, saving development time is never a reason for tolerating problems in the design. Sooner or later these problems will steal you more time than it would have taken to fix the problems in the first place

Comment: Well, my `parentObject` was of class A, so it doesn't break the law. But the class using `parentObject` certainly does. However, I feel that with your solution we can get another chain of isValid checks.

Comment: Moreover, imagine that class Z has not only a `doSomething` method, but three more methods, and Y class has its own different set of other methods, and so on. Wouldn't this fill each superclass with as many `isValidSomethingX` methods as `doSomethingX` methods in the subclass? This way, if we want to add a new method in a subclass, we need to modify also the superclass (and so breaking the open-closed principle).

Comment: Yes, you will get another chain of isValid checks. However, this chain of checks will be transparent to the caller of the initial method on parentObject. This is a huge difference to repeating the chain of checks every time you need.

Comment: A couple of questions then: What about if the method is called only once in the code? Would you modify the entire hierarchy just for a call? And second: what if it is too late to modify the design? (imagine A,B,C,D...etc as stub classes automatically generated from an XML DTD, or a web service descriptor, and subject to high modifiability in the first stages of the project).

Comment: It also will fill some of the higher level classes with methods that do nothing but delegate to class members. Now if you find that a lot of classes in your program are cluttered up with a isValidSomething() methods and so on, you might want to rethink your composition strategy. For instance, if A really really needs to invoke a method on Z, then why is Z not an instance member of A?

Comment: Laws in programming are seldom absolute laws. There are situtations where hurting this law is no problem, because the place where you hurt it is insignificant. In the case you cannot modify the structure (when you have a predifined DTD or XSD), you could write an "adapter" module that translates this structure into a nicer representation. That would also make your program more independent of changes in the DTD.

Comment: Again, A is not the client code for Z, A just knows about B, and B of C, and so on. Now there's another class (not named in the question) from where the client programmer has an `A` instance, and it has to call a method on its `Z` child node if available.

Comment: In that case, I would say A should provide a getZ() method that returns this child node or provide a method that delegates to Z, if it is available. On that note, if A calls b.getC().getD.... it knows about B, C, D and each class in this chain, not only B.

Comment: A doesn't call getB.getC. An external class (let's name it MyScreen) calls A.getB().getC()....getZ(). And Z is not in A because conceptually it is not a direct part of A. I think what you are proposing is a façade. My only objection to that would be modifiability (e.g: if I modify or remove the Z class, I must also modify the façade).

Comment: In regard to the question, i must agree with @joergl. The Law of Demeter can be ignored for some time, bus at a cost, and in the end this deep coupling will bite you. It locks the design of your classes.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Now look at point #3 here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming; and tell me if that doesn't make you free to abuse coupling and have a nice bunch of "uses" in your UML. So hey, the "law" says it's ok inside a method but not outside it?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ About the "deep coupling": An API widened enough with façade-like methods can became so verbose that some programmers will eventually forget these methods exist and just use the objects (which is the natural way of doing things). The "utility method" over a child object makes the parent class to be coupled to the child as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's bad practice to use Exceptions here.

There's a hint in the name: Exceptions are for *exceptional circumstances* (i.e. unexpected) . If nulls are expected values, then encountering them is not exceptional.

Instead, I'd have a look at the class hierarchy and try to understand why such deep access chaining needs to happen. This seems like a big design issue, you shouldn't normally expect the caller to construct calls using deep knowledge of the structure of objects hidden within class A.

Questions you could ask:

- Why does the caller need to doSomething() with the Z object anyway? Why not put the doSomething() on class A? This could propagate doSomething() down the chain if needed and if the relevant field was not null....
- What does a null *mean* if it exists in this chain? The meaning of a null will suggest what business logic should be employed to handle it.... which could be different at each level.

Overall, I suspect the right answer is to put doSomething() on each level of the heirarchy and have the implementation something like:

```
class A {
  ...
  public void doSomething() {
    B b=getB();
    if (b!=null) {
      b.doSomething();
    } else {
      // do default action in case of null B value
    }
  }
}
```

If you do this, then the API user only has to call a.doSomething(), and you have the added bonus that you can specify different default actions for a null value at each level.

Comment: The real need is to call `doSomething` on a Z instance. Imagine we cannot put this method in any other class since it is related only to fields in Z, and Z is well encapsulated. So the problem to address is not "why is doSomething on Z", but how to access Z from the root object (class A) without performing lots of null-checks in the intermediate getters.

Comment: About the null, it is used as an special value. For instance, if A.getB() returns null, it means that in the xml there was no B information inside the A tag, and this is absolutely legal. Wheter you use null, a NULL object or other value is not important. At some point, you'll have to access a nested instance in the hierarchy.

Comment: **why** is it bad practice to use Exceptions *here*?  the only rationale you give is based on a linguistic trick that's completely bogus.  *Exceptional* is **not** a synonym for *unexpected*.  those are two entirely different concepts.  I live in an earthquake zone.  I expect to live through a big one during my lifetime, and have prepared for the event.  that doesn't make it any less exceptional.  good software anticipates failure modes (or other special conditions) and handles them gracefully.  using Exceptions is one technique for doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on exactly what you're doing in the catch. In the above case, it appears that you want to call doSomething() if it's available, but if it isn't you don't care. In this case I would say that trapping the specific exception you're after is just as acceptable as a verbose check to ensure you won't throw one to begin with. There are many "null-safe" methods and extensions that use try-catch in a very similar manner to what you propose; "ValueOrDefault"-type methods are very powerful wrappers for exactly what's been done with the try-catch, for exactly the reason try-catch was used.

Try/catch is, by definition, a program flow control statement. Therefore, it is expected to be used to "control ordinary program flow"; I think the distinction you are trying to make is that it should not be used to control the "happy path" of normal error-free logic flow. Even then I might disagree; there are methods in the .NET Framework and in third-party libraries that either return the desired result or throw an exception. An "exception" is not an "error" until you cannot continue because of it; if there's something else you can try or some default case the situation can boil down to, it can be considered "normal" to receive an exception. So, catch-handle-continue is a perfectly valid use of try-catch, and many uses of exception throwing in the Framework expect you to handle them robustly.

What you want to avoid is using try/catch as a "goto", by throwing exceptions that aren't really exceptions in order to "jump" to the catch statement once some condition is satisfied. This is definitely a hack, and thus bad programming.

Comment: I agree with the "ValueOrDefault" approach in cases where the null would be handled *at the level which would encounter the null*.  A more interesting question is what to do about a scenario where encountering a null reference within a nested routine should cause an exception to reach the "main" caller (e.g. indicating that an XML file is bad).  Adding code `if (thisThing==null) throw new InvalidXmlFileException...` all over the place will slow down the main-line code.  From a pure execution standpoint, it would seem ideal...

Comment: ...to have every dereferencing operation where a `NullReferenceException` would have a known meaning, wrapped in its own catch-and-rethrow block.  From a source-code perspective, however, that would be positively monstrous.  Wrapping the outer statement in a catch-and-rethrow block would be good from an execution standpoint, but would run the risk of mislabeling a `NullReferenceException` which occurred from some other cause.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the "catch an exception" approach is that it seems a bit heavy-handed. The exception stack trace should show you where it failed since your method names make it quite clear where you are in the hierarchy but it is not a good way of going about it. Plus how would you recover from the exception and carry on to a good state of your code?

If you *must* keep this very deep hierarchy then you could use static instances of each object which defines an "empty" state. The best example I can think of which does this is the C# `string` class which has a static `string.Empty` field. Then each call of `getB()`, `getC()` ... `getZ()` would return either a real value or the "empty" state, allowing you to chain the method calls.

By making the "empty" state instances static there would only be one of each type in your system. But you would need to consider what an "empty" state looks like for each type in your hierarchy and make sure it doesn't affect any other part of your application inadvertently.

Comment: This may be the only actual choice when designing the hierarchy. It allows for concise code and doesn't fill the heap with unnecesary objects.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, they encourage the style of "easier to ask forgiveness than permission", which could be applied here to say that it's better to just optimistically try to get to Z without safety checking, and let the exception handler fix a miss.  That's easier to code, and it's more performant if the call of Z not being in the call chain is less likely than the case that it will be.

Aside from violating a bunch of OOP good design principles and exposing deeply nested private members, this code also seems vaguely dynamic in nature.  That is, you want to call method X but only if X exists on the object, and you want that logic to apply to all objects in a hierarchy of unknown length.  And you can't change the design because this is what your XML translation gives you.

Can you change languages then?  Statically-typed C# may not be the best choice for what you're doing here.  Maybe using Iron Python or some other language that's a little looser on typing will let you more easily manipulate your DOM. Once you've got the data in a stable state, you can pass that off to C# for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Using exceptions seem a poor fit here. What if one of the getters contained non-trivial logic, and threw a NullPointerException? Your code would swallow that exception without intending to. On a related note, your code samples exhibit different behaviour if `parentObject` is `null`.

Also, there really is no need to "telescope":

```
public Z findZ(A a) {
    if (a == null) return null;
    B b = a.getB();
    if (b == null) return null;
    C c = b.getC();
    if (c == null) return null;
    D d = c.getD();
    if (d == null) return null;
    return d.getZ();
}
```

Comment: in *general*, I'd agree with you, but in this case, the poster explained that this deep object hierarchy is auto-generated XML parsing code.  so, I think it's safe to say that the getters will **not** contain non-trivial logic. (sorry for the double-negative!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could provide static `isValid` methods on each class, for example for class `A` that would be:

```
public class A {
...
  public static boolean isValid (A obj) {
    return obj != null && B.isValid(obj.getB());
  }
...
}
```

And so on. Then you would have:

```
A parentObject;

if (A.isValid(parentObject)) {
  // whatever
}
```

However, although I won't get into you business I must say that such a method chaining does not say anything good about the design; maybe it's a sign of need for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that this should not need to be done, but if you must here is an option:

You could create an enumerator method once such as:

```
    public IEnumerable<type> GetSubProperties(ClassA A)
    {
        yield return A;
        yield return A.B;
        yield return A.B.C;
        ...
        yield return A.B.C...Z;
    }
```

And then use it like:

```
    var subProperties = GetSubProperties(parentObject);
    if(SubProperties.All(p => p != null))
    {
       SubProperties.Last().DoSomething();
    }
```

The enumerator will be lazily evaluated leading to no exceptions.

Comment: it will lead to exceptions if the code using the enumerator doesn't check for `NULL`s in the sequence.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ The purpose of the GetSubProperties method was only meant to be used within the context of the overall null check. In linq or a foreach they will always be returned in order.