# Test if parent objects exists

Tags: c#, .net, null-check

I am using a lot of database data in my project that is exported in different classes. For example, I have

```
transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.first();
```

The problem is that these properties are not necessarily available.

So, it is possible that `transaction.Layout` is null, it is possible that `transaction.Layout.Multimedia` is null, and so on.

I currently use this for every property:

```
if (transaction.Layout != null)
{
    if (transaction.Layout.Multimedia != null)
    {
        if (transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images != null)
        {
            if (transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.count > 0)
            {
                var img = transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.first();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way that I can check all parent classes to make sure that the property I need is available. These aren't the only objects I use, there are others as well with totally different names.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think this is what you looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080647/deep-null-checking-is-there-a-better-way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066765/is-it-acceptable-to-use-exceptions-instead-of-verbose-null-checks is related. The simple answer is there is no syntactic magic to help you do this.

Comment: There is no short way but there will be "?." operator. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not *yet*. The new version of .NET ([Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx)) has the [Null propagating operator](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543895).

Then you could do:

```
if (transaction?.Layout?.Multimedia?.Image?.count > 0)
{
    var img = transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.first();
}
```

For now, we are stuck with this. You could minimize the rows needed by concatenating the checks, like this:

```
if ( transaction.Layout != null
     && transaction.Layout.Multimedia != null
     && transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images != null
     && transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.count > 0
   )
{
    var img = transaction.Layout.Multimedia.Images.first();
}
```

There is nothing more to do.

Comment: In that case we will have to wait. Is there a release date set for this new version?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Maybe monad. More detailed description is given at [Chained null checks and the Maybe monad](http://devtalk.net/csharp/chained-null-checks-and-the-maybe-monad/)

`With` and `If`  extension methods would allow you to write:

```
var img = transaction.With(x => x.Layout)
                     .With(x => x.Multimedia)    
                     .With(x => x.Images)
                     .If(x => x.count > 0))
                     .With(x => x.first());
```

`With` method looks like:

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
  where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o);
}
```

`If` method:

```
public static TInput If<TInput>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, bool> evaluator) 
  where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o) ? o : null;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `.With(x => x.Images)` (`Images` could also be `null`...)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit OT but in theory, you could use extension methods to achieve a simpler syntax:

```
public static class GetterExtensions {
  public static LayoutClass GetLayout(this TransactionClass transaction) {
    if (transaction == null)
      return null;
    else
      return transaction.Layout;
  }
  public static MultimediaClass GetMultimedia(this LayoutClass layout) {
    if (layout == null)
       return null;
    else
       return layout.Multimedia;
  }
  public static ImagesClass GetImages(this MultimediaClass multimedia) {
    if (multimedia == null)
       return null;
    else
       return multimedia.Images;
  }
  public static int? GetCount(this ImagesClass images) {
    if (images == null)
       return null;
    else
       return images.count;
  }
}
```

(Where `LayoutClass`, `MultimediaClass` etc. are the types of the respective properties).

Having this, you could write

```
if (transaction.GetLayout().GetMultimedia().GetImages().GetCount() > 0)
  // ...
```

This solution makes use of the fact, that extension methods can be called on `null` objects without throwing an exception. They simply get `null` as their `this` parameter in this case. Also not the `int?` return type (`Nullable<int>`) of the `GetCount()` method, which allows to return `null` for an integer property.

But if you have many objects (with many properties) this solution is probably impractical and requires a lot of additiona maintenance effort. Also, writing `GetLayout()` instead of simply `Layout` is still less elegant.