# Handle != null check for two variable

Tags: java

I have below code, which i am checking not null check for two variables.

```
 if (userParameter != null || configurationParameter != null){
   add.userParameter();
   add.configurationParameter();
 }
```

Is there any way I can check for not `null` in one `if`condition like `if((userParameter or configurationParameter) != null)` in java.

Comment: What are you trying to archieve with that?

Comment: yeah question is unclear

Comment: Not strictly related but I think that in your code there should be && operator. If both are not null then operate, am I right?

Comment: I would suggest to replace the ``||`` with ``&&``, but i honestly don't understand your question.

Comment: do these two variables belong to any class/object? if yes then you only check if that object is null. Like lets say userParameter and configurationParameter belong to Test class, then you only test if test is null like this: if (Test != null) ...

Comment: @Faraz Durrani The check on the both variables should be performed at a time or at another time.

Comment: with something like this `public static boolean isNull(Object... args)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check multiple objects for nullity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582524/how-to-check-multiple-objects-for-nullity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have two parameters, the most you can do is to create a method that return `true` or `false` depending on the check:

```
 if (checkForNull(userParameter, configurationParameter)){
   add.userParameter();
   add.configurationParameter();
 }

 private boolean checkForNull(Object... objects){
    for (Object obj : objects){
        if (obj == null){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

**EDITED**

As @shmosel and @AxelH proposed, The method would be more effiecient using varargs. Thanks for the improvement

Comment: If you're going with helper methods, might as well go all out: `boolean checkForNull(Object... objects) { for (Object obj : objects) if (obj == null) return false; return true; }`

Comment: Same comment, using varargs made this way more usefull. ( I have just wrote this in comment section)

Comment: You will only check the first argument with this. The `return true` should be after the loop, when you are sure none are `null` ;)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting varargs would be more efficient, just more useful.

Comment: `checkForNull` can be a confusing name for a method that checks for no nulls. Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis on the first line.

Answer (score 7):

> There is no way to compare null(single) thing with multiple
>   things(i.e. userParameter & configurationParameter) in java.

But you can write a method like below, use it when you are checking multiple values for null with || :-

```
public boolean isNull(Object... args){
for(Object arg: args){
  if(arg==null) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Why a `String` ? `Object` works better

Comment: My method is just a hint. Type of parameters not mentioned in question, so just assumed them to be String.

Comment: Well, in case of `null` check, the type doesn't matter, you can't do it on a primitve, that's all. So you can be generic ;)

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, your current code already will only be checking one condition, because the `||` operator short-circuits.  It is the case that if the condition `userParameter != null` be true, then the JVM won't even check the other condition.

Besides this, there is no way as far as I know to check for `null` in two separate varibles in a single comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is the ternary operator `?` (the conditional operator):

```
 if (userParameter != null ? configurationParameter != null : false) {
```

(Note: The logic is different from your code, you probably want to check if both are not null)
However, using the features everybody else is using too is probably a good idea.

Comment: This is identical to `if (userParameter != null && configurationParameter != null) {`. As a rule of thumb, you should never need a boolean literal in a ternary operation.

Comment: Nit: its correct name is the [*conditional operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), which is *a* ternary operator (and currently the only ternary operator).

Comment: @shmosel Yes, I know the logic is different (see the note I added) because I think this is what the OP should use. And I completely agree this should not be used in real code (see my last line).

Comment: I didn't complain about the logic. My problem is with the unnecessary use of a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You may Use `Binary Operator`
[Check Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

or you can use the `ternary Operator`.

Comment: That wouldn't be the same as with `&&` or `||`